# Displaying Custom Attributes in Documentum - Webtop

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, webtop

I am following [an article](http://developer.emc.com/developer/Articles/DisplayCustomAttributesInWebtop.htm) that explains how to use the ICustomAttributeDataHandler class.

I am creating a custom column for the inbox screen, but the problem is that the value I set for my custom attribute is not being reflected on the screen.

As a test I am changing the task name to "whoKnows". But this code is not effecting what is output on the screen:

```
ICustomAttributeRecordSet.setCustomAttributeValue(i, "taskName", "whoKnows");
```

(I am able to print debug lines from my custom class when the inbox is viewed, so I know my code is being run.)

Someone on the comments of that article wrote:

> the user must call the
>   "setCustomAttributesInQuery() method
>   on the dataprovider passing in a
>   string array of the custom attributes

...what does that meen? Could this be my problem?

thanks.

Comment: a little more detail would help.  Have you added the xml column configuration to the inbox component definition?  What is showing up?  what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I have already used Webtop, but just as an user. I found a [post in the dm developer discussion group](http://www.dmdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=13518) that can be useful, though:

> For creating a custom column in the
>   doclist you dont need to go through
>   this complex procedures. You can use
>   custom attribute datahandlers for
>   this.
>
> 1. First in your object list component xml file add your custom column
>      definition in the "columns" tag. You
>      can even add static columns instead of
>      the documentum attributes.
> 2. Now create a class which implements the ICustomAttributeDataHandler.
> 3. Implement the default the methods getRequiredAttributes and the getData
>      function.
> 4. In getRequiredAttributes add attributes of the object that you are
>      looking for.
> 5. In your getdata method retrieve each row and then based on the
>      attribute that you see, just set the
>      value that you want to. 6) Finally
>      define your class in the app.xml file
>
> There is a section in WDK developement
>   guide regarding
>   ICustomAttribuetDataHandlers. Look for
>   the topic named "Adding custom
>   attributes to a datagrid".

I'm not sure if this is the final solution, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question about setCustomAttributesInQuery()

every datagrid in WDK is backed by an underlying data provider.  You can get this proivder by using the following code.

```
Datagrid datagrid = (Datagrid)getControl("doclist_grid",com.documentum.web.form.control.databound.Datagrid.class);
DataProvider dp = datagrid.getDataProvider();
```

Once you've done that, you can call

```
dp.setCustomAttributesInQuery(myArr);
```

I'm not actually sure if this is part of the solution to your problem, but you could try this and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the inbox component.

if using classic view, go to inboxlist component and add your custom attribute.

```
<column>
    <attribute>CustomAttributeName</attribute>
    <label>Custom Attribute Label</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
</column>
```

Your custom attribute has to be in a custom type that is a sub type of dmi_queue_item, because inboxlist shows only dmi_queue_item objects.

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tejas.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a non-issue, but based on your code, I can't tell if you're doing this:

```
ICustomAttributeRecordSet.setCustomAttributeValue(i, "taskName", "whoKnows");
```

or this:

```
ICustomAttributeRecordSet rs;
rs.setCustomAttributeValue(i, "taskName", "whoKnows");
```

You should be calling the setCustomAttributeValue method on the rs object instance, not on the interface.

Comment: Thanks, but I indeed am calling the method on the object instance.

Comment: Can you provide more code?  The code provided in the article works... We now have to figure out what the differences are in yours and theirs